# Call command will not run remote batch file

Tags: batch-file, blat

I created a batch to scan a server (Windows Server 2008 R2) for certain file names. If the file(s) are found it will run another batch `email.bat`that will send out an email notification. My issue is that I cannot get the call command to run the `email.bat` from within the scan batch. Below is the code that I have created for the original scan batch. I included an `if exist` statement because I only want the email to go out if the listed file is found during the scan. What could I be doing wrong?

```
set log=c:\Scan\scanresult.txt
set err=c:\Scan\scanerror.err
set file=testfile.*


cd\
echo ------------------------------ >%log%
HOSTNAME >>%log% 2>%err%
echo ------------------------------ >>%log%
echo.                   >>%log%
echo.                   >>%log%
C:
dir %file% /s /Q 1>>%log% 2>>%err%
D:
dir %file% /s /Q 1>>%log% 2>>%err%
E:
dir %file% /s /Q 1>>%log% 2>>%err%
F:
dir %file% /s /Q 1>>%log% 2>>%err%
G:
dir %file% /s /Q 1>>%log% 2>>%err%
H:
dir %file% /s /Q 1>>%log% 2>>%err%
I:
dir %file% /s /Q 1>>%log% 2>>%err%  
J:
dir %file% /s /Q 1>>%log% 2>>%err%
K:
dir %file% /s /Q 1>>%log% 2>>%err%


if exist "c:\Scan\scanresult.txt" (
    call "c:\Scan\email.bat")
```

Comment: Well your code is flawed from the beginning.  The `DIR` command in its current form will always output something to scanresult.txt.

Comment: You say it is a remote batch but I do not see anything in your code that makes it look like it is running any remote batch files.

Comment: Hey Squashman, I believe I was able to get the call command to work; but yes I am trying to output the results of the scan for each drive to the scanresult.txt file then input it to the email.bat to send out. Right now I am getting too much data... all I need is for the report to list the number of files found and their directory path.